# Adding Commands to Grub2

Tags: linux, fedora, grub

So I'm trying to add a "apple_set_os" command to Grub2 by applying the following patch:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2013-12/msg00442.html

Grub compiles fine, and the "applesetos.model" and "applesetos.mod" files appear in /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/ .  But grub2 says that this command is not found.  Is there an extra step to add commands to Grub?

Comment: Apparently I was missing the "insmod applesetos" command that I needed to include prior to the apple_set_os.  Also, I needed to put the .mod files in the "/EFI/fedora/x86_64-efi" (for my system) path.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was missing the "insmod applesetos" command that I needed to include prior to the apple_set_os. Also, I needed to put the .mod files in the "/EFI/fedora/x86_64-efi" (for my system) path. – user2602914